# Jupyter Notebook: Change Data Rate Limit Inside Active Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook where an executed cell gives the following error:

IOPub data rate exceeded...

I understand this is an option:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

However, I would really prefer to just to set this along with my import statements and other notebook settings instead of tweaking configuration files or command line when starting notebooks.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I have not looked into again since then though.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend creating an alias `jn` to launch Jupyter notebook with these settings every time. You do it once for all and do not have to tweak with command line after.
Under UNIX system you run in terminal ::

```
alias jn="jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=2147483647"
```

To enable this alias at every session you have to append this command line to your shell config file, by default `~/.bash_profile`

If you run Windows check the equivalence to [aliases](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line)