# IOPub data rate exceeded - in JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a **JUPYTERLAB** notebook  where an executed cell gives the following error:

IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

I have followed the instructions in this other thread - [Jupyter Notebook: Change Data Rate Limit Inside Active Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235621/jupyter-notebook-change-data-rate-limit-inside-active-notebook)

& when I open the jupyter notebook it works correctly but when I try to open it on jupyterLabs I keep getting the error.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue for jupyterlabs?

thanks

Comment: I am glad you found my answer useful ! No idea for jupyter lab though

Answer (score 3):

For Anyone confused about this for **JupyterLab** specifically, in anaconda prompt or cmd, try:

`jupyter lab --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10`

Answer (score 0):

Before you change the variable that sets this threshhold, it might be worth to note that if you're writing to a variable too much data, and then you want to print the value (accumulated) within that variable to the screen you will get this message.
in my case that happened and it was resolve making sure that the amount of data being put on an the variable was not big. I was logging thousands of lines to a variable that I letter was printing to the screen (client), this was in fact an error in my code doing the logging as in most cases if you're printing the value of variable, it should't be too big for jupyterlab not being able to handle it.